# How do I host a windowless Flash Player?

Tags: c++, flash, com, activex

I would like to use windowless activation for a Flash Player control. Unfortunately, there is a very low amount of documentation available about this, even on MSDN. Most articles I found describe related issues, or how to make your own AX control support windowless activation. I have found some articles describe the **hosting** process (which I want), but with ATL. However, I already have an application, utilizing Qt and using the mingw-gcc compiler, in which it is probably not easy to incorporate.

I would like to learn the most possibly basic way of painting a windowless ActiveX control somewhere (on a DC?), and sending keyboard/mouse events to it. Links or detailed advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could you live with a window that has no border and is the same size as the player (which is a child)?

Comment: I left out the most important part: my motivation is that this way I can use dirty-rectangle redrawing instead of full redrawing for each frame. Is that possible with the solution that you describe?

Comment: Well you can make the window never really *do* what you don't want it to do. Just handle the appropriate messages.

Comment: The problem with Flash Player is that in windowed mode (where it paints itself) it will repaint the its whole contents every time. I can't just filter out the WM_PAINT messages, because I do want it to be painted. But (and that's why I want windowless activation) to only repaint the dirty rectangles, I need to paint it myself. If this is possible with the solution you have in mind, I'm all ears.